# Can't store text-box value in variable

Tags: javascript, html, variables

I'm trying to create a simple chatroom program that receives data from an html text-box and displays it inside a container. I try to achieve this by setting the text-box value to a newly created paragraph element, but for some reason I cannot store the text-box value into another variable.

When I console.log the text variable it should display the text I entered, but it only displays an empty string.

```
const container = document.querySelector('.container');
let textBox = document.querySelector('.text-box');
let para = document.createElement('p');
let text = textBox.value;

 /*
textBox.addEventListener('keyup', (event) => {
    if (event.keycode === 13) {

    }
})
*/

para.textContent = text;
container.appendChild(para);
```

```
//console.log(textBox.value) => displays the value that I enter into the field.
//console.log(text) => displays ""
```

Comment: What have you written in the HTML textBox that you expect to see?

Comment: `textBox.value` is `''` when you assign it to that `text` variable, which is immutable. In layman's terms, a String does not automatically change just because you access it later.

Comment: anything. if i write "hello" and then log the text-box value in the console it shows up as "hello". the problem is trying to store that value into another variable so i can display it on the screen.

Comment: Thank you StackSlave for the info, that helps with some of my confusion. I just figured out that the 'c' in 'keycode' should be capitalized. Now everything is working, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can try replacing
para.textContent = text Box.value

I hope it solve the problem.

Thanks.